# How to tell Linux Mint 15 where to find OS updates?

Tags: linux-mint, updates

I am trying to install updates for my Linux mint 15 VM. The VM's connection is configured as NAT, ultimately using my workstation with Windows 7 internet's connection. However, when I try to update this machine by going to the terminal and typing `sudo apt-get update` I receive some updates, about 30% of all and this is an omitted example of the updates that gets ignored:

```
Get:8 http://packages.linuxmint.com helena/main Sources [4,520B]   
Get:9 http://packages.linuxmint.com helena/upstream Sources [3,007B]   
Get:10 http://packages.linuxmint.com helena/import Sources [994B]     
Get:11 http://packages.linuxmint.com helena/backport Sources [20B]   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/main Packages   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/restricted Packages   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/universe Packages   
Ign http://archive.ubuntu.com karmic-updates/multiverse Packages   
Ign http://deb.opera.com stable/non-free Packages
```

My first guess would be that those links are either broken, expired or maybe Linux Mint has them already installed. So where does Linux look / get the hyperlinks to look for the updates?

Comment: Where it looks depends on the distrubution. There isn't a single location. The default configuraton should be correct as your running the current release of `Linux Mint` you sure this isn't the case of you simply already have the current update installed? I guarantee you the sources fo the packages in `Linux Mint 15` are correct.  The user manual has everything you need to know how to install updates on Mint. http://www.linuxmint.com/documentation/user-guide/english_15.0.pdf

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[ign simply means there's nothing new](https://askubuntu.com/questions/294525/what-does-ign-mean-when-running-an-apt-get-update) so apt can't be bothered to download it.  This is *perfectly fine*. Debian based distributions usually store a main repository list in /etc/apt/source.list .

There is ***NOTHING*** wrong with your current source list, outside of there being no new updates uploaded by the distro. Consider using backports or upgrading to a newer release if you *must* have newer packages, but as is *everything is working as designed*.